# Passing Custom Var to the script in Audit

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I'm writing a dynamic inventory script to work with Ansible Playbook. I'm looking for a way to pass a custom var extracted from the inventory script to use in a task in my playbook.

My inventory from the script provides the following info as expected

```
    "vars": {
        "ansible_ssh_user": ADMIN_ACCOUNT,
        "ansible_ssh_private_key_file": CERT_PART,
        "ansible_become": "yes",
        "ansible_become_method": "sudo",
        "server_name: $serverName,
    }
```

Now I want the value of $serverName is passed to a script in one of my task in playbook, for example:

```
  - name: Execute an audit script
    script: /etc/ansible/audit_server.sh {{ server_name }}
    register: output
```

My audit_server.sh would simply need to accept $serverName parameter, for example

```
serverName=$1
name=$(get something -s $serverName)
```

I'm not sure if Ansible natively supports such a use of variable.

Comment: If your inventory is returning a `server_name` variable as you show in your example, you can just refer to that in your ansible playbooks.  `/etc/ansible/audit_server.sh {{ server_name }}`

Comment: I updated the playbook as it was a typo

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for you:

```
  - name: Execute an audit script
    script: "/etc/ansible/audit_server.sh {{ server_name }}" 
    register: output
```